# Telegram Bot execute callback on click of inline query result

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to use inline mode for new bot.
My use case:
When someone types `@my_bot abc` I want to call `find_parties(update)` to display all of their available parties as inline results. Once the user clicks on one of the parties, I want to call `associate_string(update, party)` in order to persist `abc` into my database. Currently, my inline handler looks like this:

```
def inline_handling(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    if not query:
        return

    inline_options = []
    for party in find_parties(update):
        inline_options.append(
            InlineQueryResultArticle(
                id=party['id'],
                title=party['name'],
                input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(party['name'])
        )
    )
    context.bot.answer_inline_query(update.inline_query.id, inline_options)
```

With this handler, I'm just displaying all party names and when one of them is clicked, that name is send to the chat.

If it were possible, I would like to replace the `InlineQueryResultArticle` with some kind of inline query callback result that calls `associate_string`. Sadly, I haven't found any implementation of `InlineQueryResult` that uses callbacks.
I did find another object called `CallbackQuery` in the docs, but I have no idea how I can use it in inline queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior I was describing doesn't exist for Telegram Bots. However, there is a ChosenInlineResultHandler, which will be called whenever an InlineQuery has been executed by a user.